# No data displaying on Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

Im trying to build a Java/Spring Boot application connected to MySQL. The application compiles fine and I don't run into any errors. When I go to localhost:8080/employees, the webpage is supposed to display the Employee ID (eid), Employee Name (name) and Employee Salary (salary) from an sql file that has been imported into MySQL through the terminal. When I go to localhost:8080/employees, the webpage displays '[]'.

Repository class

```
package com.example.demo.repositories;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import com.example.demo.models.Employee;

public interface EmployeeRespositoryImpl extends CrudRepository <Employee, Integer> {
    
    public List<Employee>findByEidAndNameAndSalary(String eid, String name, Double salary);

}
```

Service Class

```
package com.example.demo.services;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.demo.models.Employee;
import com.example.demo.repositories.EmployeeRespositoryImpl;

@Service
public class EmployeeService {
    
    @Autowired
    EmployeeRespositoryImpl er;
    
    public List<Employee> allEmployees(String eid, String name, Double salary){
        return er.findByEidAndNameAndSalary(eid, name, salary);
    }

}
```

Controller Class

```
package com.example.demo.controllers;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.models.Employee;
import com.example.demo.services.EmployeeService;
@RestController
public class EmployeeControllers {
    
    @Autowired
    EmployeeService es;
    
    @GetMapping(path="/employees")
    public List<Employee> getEmployees(String eid, String name, Double salary) {
        return es.allEmployees(eid, name, salary);
    }
    
}
```

//Models Class

```
package com.example.demo.models;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;


@Entity
public class Employee {
    
    @Id     
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String eid;
    private String name;
    private double salary;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Department dept;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Project> projects;
    public String getEid() {
        return eid;
    }
    public void setEid(String eid) {
        this.eid = eid;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public Department getDept() {
        return dept;
    }
    public void setDept(Department dept) {
        this.dept = dept;
    }
    public List<Project> getProjects() {
        return projects;
    }
    public void setProjects(List<Project> projects) {
        this.projects = projects;
    }

}
```

Application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/import?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Adal135792!
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=off
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

server.error.include-message=always
server.error.include-binding-errors=always
```

SQL file

```
INSERT INTO employee (id, eid, name, salary, dept_id) VALUES (1, "E001", "Thomas", 55000, 1);
INSERT INTO employee (id, eid, name, salary, dept_id) VALUES (2, "E002", "Mary", 59000, 1);
INSERT INTO employee (id, eid, name, salary, dept_id) VALUES (3, "E003", "John", 72401, 3);
INSERT INTO employee (id, eid, name, salary, dept_id) VALUES (4, "E004", "Sean", 65432, 3);
INSERT INTO employee (id, eid, name, salary, dept_id) VALUES (5, "E005", "Ann", 62003, 3);
INSERT INTO employee (id, eid, name, salary, dept_id) VALUES (6, "E006", "Alan", 47333, 2);
INSERT INTO employee (id, eid, name, salary, dept_id) VALUES (7, "E007", "Sara", 55323, 4);
INSERT INTO employee (id, eid, name, salary, dept_id) VALUES (8, "E008", "Bill", 52353, 4);
INSERT INTO employee (id, eid, name, salary, dept_id) VALUES (9, "E009", "Rob", 57000, 5);
```

Comment: And you post everything and leave out hte web page which has the error... Also it doesn't show everything only that what matches the query.

Comment: Please can you show the sql file ? Because your Restcontroller `@GetMapping(path="/employees")`  seems to give you an empty list. Maybe your database is empty ? Can you check inside your database, if there are user 's values ?

Comment: `findByEidAndNameAndSalary` means that it will return records which match the given values. It looks as though you are not providing any values. Please read some spring boot tutorials.

Comment: First, paste the content of application.properties file here or wherever you have your DataSource configurations. Check the MySQL Dirver dependency in your POM file, if it is not there add it. Meanwhile, Check the query generated by hibernate in the console. Copy that and execute it directly on your MySQL Server. If you cannot see the query in console. Add this property in application.properties file "spring.jpa.show-sql=true"

Comment: @QuentinGenet the data is in SQL and when I run the spring boot application, it feeds the data into MySQL

Comment: In your entity, your `id` is `int`, maybe you should replace it by an `Integer` because in your repository your id is Integer.

Comment: You are filtering data by `eid, name and salary` in repository and you never supply this parameters to rest endpoint so this values are null. Then your repo doesn't find any data, that has null as value in database, and returns empty list. 
You need to use @PathVariable or/and @RequestParam and provide values to the rest endpoint.

Comment: @AdamDalton cool ! Can you accept my answer to share solution please ?

Answer (score 0):

According to your endpoint "/employees" , you need to return all employees. So why are you not using `.findAll()` method from your repository instead of seeking employee with 3 differents parameters ?